# How to post data from a simple form with jQuery to PHP script for Twilio, to text link to an app

Tags: php, jquery, twilio

I'm looking for some help integrating Twilio into a WordPress site.

I am using a jQuery script to pass on the entered data (the cell number), but I can't figure out what I need to write in the array in the php script called by my form so that the entered cell number data is input into the (right now it says "cellnumber data from form") to include array.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery( "#sendsms" ).click(function() {
var num = jQuery.trim(jQuery('.phone_us').val());

if (num.length < 11){
alert('Invalid Phone Number');
return;
}
console.log(num);
jQuery.ajax({
url: "path/to/sms.php",
type:'GET',
data: 'num=' + num
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( msg );
});
});
});
</script>
```

then the form looks like this:

sms.php looks like this (stripped out the personal data):

```
require "path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$people = array(
"cellnumber data from form" => "User",
);
foreach ($people as $number => $name) {
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
"XXX-XXX-XXXX", 
$number,
"Hi there, thank you for your interest in OUR APP. Here's your link: itunes.com/APP"
);
echo "Thank you! You will receive a text with the link shortly.";
}
```

I need the input cell from the form to post to the area "cellnumber data from form" but I'm not sure what to include in the php script to catch that data.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    require "twilio/Services/Twilio.php";

    // Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $AuthToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);



 $number = $_POST['number']; OR $number = $_GET['number']; // Depends how you get number via GET method or POST Method
 //$message = $_POST['message'];
        $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

        // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
        // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
            "Twilio Number", 

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            $number,

            // the sms body
            "Hello World"
        );
 ?>
```

You are using GET Method so you have to use $number = $_GET['num'];

Answer (score 0):

I think you just mean to catch the submitted data?

Basically your Javascript is just making a GET call to the path/to/sms.php

So in order to use the number in your PHP just:

```
$number = $_GET["num"];
$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
"XXX-XXX-XXXX", 
$number,
"Hi there, thank you for your interest in OUR APP. Here's your link: itunes.com/APP"
);
```

The $_GET should have that data from your ajax call right in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! So it would look like this? I'm not familiar with ajax: 'require "path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php"; $AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; $AuthToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken); $people = array( "cellnumber data from form" => "User", ); foreach ($people as $number => $name) { $number = $_GET["num"];$sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage( "XXX-XXX-XXXX", $number, "Hi there, thank you for your interest in OUR APP. Here's your link: itunes.com/APP" ); echo "Thank you! You will receive a text with the link shortly."; }'

Comment: Yeah.   That should work.  Do a var_dump on the $number to make sure it is getting in there.    You should also read up on the developer console so you can see the response to your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
<?php
require "/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";
$AccountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$AuthToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
$number = $_GET['num'];
try{
$message = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(
'XXX-XXX-XXXX', // From a valid Twilio number
$number, // Text this number
"Hello World."
 );
 } catch (Exception $e) {
 echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 die();
 } echo 'Success. You will receive a text with the link shortly.';
 ?>
```